# Multidimensional Array 3x3 Average in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, matrix

I am stuck with my C program where I have to calculate the averages of a multidimensional array by a function.

Let's say you have the following array:

```
array[5][8];
```

I am already able to calculate the average of the whole array through a function.
But, in the exercise, you have to calculate the averages of a 3x3 dimensional arrays inside of the 5x8 array and the results have to be written into another array.

It should look something like this (meaning the 3x3 matrix can overlap):

[image: It should look something like this]

This is how my function looks so far (it just calculates the sum of the whole matrix). The user can decide the size and values of the array.

```
void matavg(float *matrixIn, float *matrixOut, int rows, int cols, float *avg) {


float sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        sum += *(matrixIn+i * cols+j);

    }
}


*avg = sum /(rows*cols);
```

How can I rewrite my function so that only the average of 3x3 elements are consecutively calculated inside of the input array?

`*matrixIn` is the matrix that is created by the user; `*matrixOut` should be the matrix with the average values.

Comment: For each destination element, add the values of the corresponding 3×3 elements in the source array, then divide by 9.

Comment: Take the coordinates in of the top left corner of every possible 3x3 matrix. Iterate over all those coordinates, meaning iterating over both sides of the full matrix minus 2. Now in two separate (nested) loops, for every "top left corner" iterate from 0 to 2 for both the x and y coordinates (add then to the coordinates of "top left". Add all numbers together and divide by 9.  Put that in the destination array at the coordinates of the "top left".

Comment: Look up convolution.

Answer (score 0):

```
//sq - size of the square subarray. 
void matavg3x3(size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t sq, float (*matrixIn)[cols], float (*matrixOut)[sq]) 
{
    for(size_t rowstart = 0; rowstart <= rows - sq; rowstart++)
    {
        for(size_t colstart = 0; colstart <= cols - sq; colstart++)
        {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for(size_t row = 0; row < sq; row++)
            {
                for(size_t col = 0; col < sq; col++)
                {
                    sum += matrixIn[rowstart + row][colstart + col];
                }                
            }
            matrixOut[rowstart][colstart] = sum / (sq * sq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `float *matrixOut` combined with `matrixOut[rowstart][colstart]` looks like a compilation error

Comment: @tstanisl indeed forgot to amend first line